# How to modify codes from an deployed application package in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, package

we have an asp.net application developed by a third party. We would like to migrate the application to another server and possibly add new futures to it. The third party has provided us the deployed application(with all the code files) in a zip file.  Since zip file does not contain any project file(.proj) or solution file, I tried to create a new project and then add the existing files to the project, but while i tried compile, i received many errors such as "control gridview1 is not declared. "

My question is, while adding all those  wondering is there a way to open the deployed application in visual studio 2010, make change to it, and then compile? Or do i need to have the original project file or solution file in order to compile?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you and regards,

gina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you recieved a web site instead of a project.  In visual studio 'File'->'Open'->'Web Site'.  You should be able to compile/edit/publish from there.

Comment: Thank you so much Justin. I know it should be easy.